# Default location of GPS coordinates

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, gps, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7-emulator

I am using GPS in my WP7 application. When I run the application in emulator the GPS give me some default coordinates of some place around Seatle in United states. The application runs fine on wp device and give the rite coordinated. What I need is some how change the default coordinates that GPS returns when running the application on emulator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can click on the arrows in the emulator to see these tools (location tab) :

[image]